# Which is more efficient : char a[10]; OR char *a; a = malloc(10);

Tags: c

i notice in a function this will not work:

```
char a[10];
sprintf(a, "test");
return a;
```

but this works:

```
char *a;
a = malloc(10);
sprintf(a, "test");
return a;
```

**QUESTION**: if i do not have to "**return a;**".. 
is it better to use "**char a[10];**" ? if so. why ?

Comment: `return a;` is _undefined behavior_ (UB) - returning the address of a local non-`static` variable.  Do not use that code.

Comment: this code block `char a[10];
sprintf(a, "test");
return a;` should be: `char a[10] = {'\0'};
sprintf(a, "test");
return a;`  however, the local variable `a[]` will go out of scope when the function exits.  That is why the code needs to us a heap allocation function.  I would strongly suggest using `calloc()` rather than `malloc()` so the allocated memory will contain a known value.  Also, always check (!=NULL) the returned value from the heap allocation functions to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: if the code were to NOT be returning `a[]` then the `char a[30]` is much better as it is generated at compile time rather than at run time.  I.E. this method of declaring `a[30];` does not require a function call at run time so is much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc` is a function call into the standard library. Depending on current heap fragmentation and heap organisation of the compiler, this may be an expensive operation (even the call into the library alone may consume more CPU cycles than a stack allocation).

`char a[10]` is an increment of the stack frame (rather: works out to a simple subtraction of 10 from the current stack pointer).

Stack allocation is definitively faster on most non-exotic architectures.

Comment: @chux that was not the question, it even is mentioned as *known* in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you do not have to `return a;` or store a reference to `a` anywhere outside of the function, then `a` is only going to be used locally within the function, so it is perfectly fine to declare `a` as a local variable.  That's precisely why they are called *local variables*.

Also, declaring `a` as a local will incur a ***zero*** performance penalty, in contrast to `malloc()` which is rather slow.